# why gives error Expression cannot contain lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get single object from list

```
Node node= ListNodes.where(n=>n.path=="c:\\test").single();
```

OR

```
Node node= ListNodes.Single(n=>n.path=="c:\\test");
```

Where ListNodes is list of Node class

But both codes gives me error,

> Expression cannot contain lambda expressions.

Could anyone tell me, what is wrong?

Comment: What type is `ListNodes`?

Comment: just a sidenote - i'd change string to `@"c:\test"` - as **\t** is an escape sequence

Comment: ListNodes is list of Node class

Comment: Did you added `System.LINQ` namespace in your page ??

Comment: Is this a compiler error? or a runtime error? What is the context of this code? i.e. where is it? is it inside something else complex? Also, is this a .cs file? or is it something like razor? or the immediate window? or...?

Comment: Maybe you are trying to see evalute expression while deubbging (f.e. Immediate Window)?

Comment: its runtime error, not compile time

Comment: If it is runtime error then you definitely trying to get the result in immediate window or watch window. LINQ expression dont give you result there

Comment: @Sam are you very sure that is a runtime error? because: if that is a "list of Node class" (as stated), then at runtime it **isn't a lambda expression**: it is a delegate.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: be careful with "isn't a lambda expression: it is a delegate". When it's Where of queryable (but in this case i don't think so) it is not delegate - it's `Expression` instance.

Comment: @pwas which is why context is so very important; the only context we have here is "Where ListNodes is a list of Node class", in which case: `Enumerable.Where`

Comment: I'm still dubious because list doesn't necessarily mean `System.Collections.Generic` but I couldn't find another implementation of `Where` that doesn't need a lambda, I think Marc's answer is probably the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a message that appears in the Immediate Window. It occurs because lambda expressions usually involve captured scopes that **change the entire structure of the code**; fine to do during compilation, but not something that can happen on the fly during debugging. Hence: this is not supported in the Immediate Window.

[image]

There are probably *some* lambdas that *could* be processed successfully in the Immediate Window without a rewrite (and yours is probably one of them), but:

- a feature that works *some* of the time tends to cause even more confusion
- it would still take effort to scope, design, implement, test, document, translate and support - and that effort has clearly been spent elsewhere so far

Answer (score 0):

you need to use escape character.

```
Node node= ListNodes.Single(n=>n.path=="c:\\test");
```

or

```
Node node= ListNodes.Single(n=>n.path==@"c:\test");
```

Comment: try with Node node= ListNodes.Single(n=>n.path.Contains(@"c:\test")); or try with Node node= ListNodes.Single(n=>n.path.Equals(@"c:\test"));

Comment: `Contains` is quite different to `Equals`. Bad comment.

Comment: Expression cannot contain **lambda** expressions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a capital 'W' in Where.
2. When you have paths a '\' needs to be '\'. Use a '@' before your strings.

If the two above don't work then:

We don't know what type ListNode is. My guess is that it either doesn't have an extension function called 'Where' or 'Single' or you are missing a 'using System.Linq' statement in your code.

```
using System.Linq;

// blah blah

Node node= ListNodes.Where(n=>n.path == @"c:\test").Single();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like below:

```
        var ListNodes = new List<Node>() { new Node { path = "c:\\test" } };
        Node node = ListNodes.Where(n => n.path == "c:\\test").Single();
```